# extract formatted text and also href link from html using c#

Tags: c#, html, html-to-text

I am trying to extract text and also link which is in href.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>foo <a href='http://www.example.com'>bar</a>
            <br> baz</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am looking for output as, `foo http://www.example.com bar baz` 
br tag should be consider so to get correct formatted sentence.

Comment: You can use the `HTMLAgilityPack` for your purposes: https://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: Thank you @RahulSharma. Is it possible to provide example for this use case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried but I do not have the required reputations to accept the answer. I am new to stack overflow. @RahulSharma

Comment: If my answer helped you out, you can accept it by clicking on the tick box next to the answer. @Aishwarya Gujjar

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html =
        @"<html><body><p>foo <a href='http://www.example.com'>bar</a><br> baz</p></body></html> ";
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        var htmlAnchor = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a");
        var htmlBr = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p");
        string hrefValue = htmlAnchor.Attributes["href"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(htmlBr.InnerText + " " + hrefValue);
    }
}
```

Output:

> foo bar baz http://www.example.com

Working Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BBYAF9